# How to pass a URL input parameter value to Blazor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

This passes a value into a blazor component

```
[Parameter]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

But what about passing a value from the URL input parameter?

Comment: Add a `@page "/path/to/page/{id:string}"` ?

Comment: https://dev.to/bradwellsb/pass-data-between-blazor-pages-using-route-parameters-3p85

Comment: try await Http.PutJsonAsync($"/path/to/page/{Id}, value);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A public property defined within a component, and annotated with the Parameter attribute serves the purpose of either storing a Component parameter passed to a child component from its parent component, as for instance, the following code pass a string parameter from a parent component to its child component.

### ParentComponent.razor

`<ChildComponent Title="I'm a child component" />`

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<p>@Title</p>

@code{
     public string Title { get; set; } = "Default Title";
}
```

or, storing the value of a route data, as for instance, the route data Start in the URL  https://localhost:44396/counter/123, which is automatically done by the framework, if you define a public property named Start, and annotate it with the Parameter attribute:

### Counter.razor

```
    @page "/counter"
@page "/counter/{start:int}"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @Start</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int Start { get; set; }


    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        Start++;
    }
}
```

Note that the definition of the Counter component contains two route templates. The first route template is set to use the default value of the Start property; that is the value 0. But the user can change the default value by providing a route parameter in the URL, as for instance: *https://localhost:44396/counter/123*. Now when the button is clicked, the start value is 123, not 0. Just for the record, the second template contains a route constraint, which constrains the app to only work with int values.

Comment: Could you please tell a solution for multiple variables ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's in the doc : [components routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#routing)

Comment: routing does not work in mainlayout? :) only in a razor component!

Comment: @001 - if  that is the problem then you need to ask a much better question.

Answer (score 0):

> a blazor page is actually a blazor component starts with `@page` directive.

> in fact all blazor components just a razor component with an extension of `.razor`

so, when you use url to redirect page by url you should *override* the `OnParameterSet()` or `OnParameterSetAsync()`

that is my understanding as a conclusion of my blazor experience. please feel free about any corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Use **/{Id:int?}** in @page route string *IndustryAddEdit.razor* :

```
@page "/IndustryAddEdit/{Id:int?}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

*IndustriesList.razor* :

```
@foreach (var industry in Industries)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@industry.Title</td>
        <td><EditBtn Href=@($"IndustryAddEdit/{industry.Id}") /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

*EditBtn.razor* in Share folder :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Href" title="Edit">
    <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill"></i>
</a>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public required string Href { get; set; }
}
```