# Write variable in Url - Blazor

Tags: c#, html, url, blazor

I would like to put a variable which I set in a text box in my URL, behind my domain name. Like this:

https://localhost:44305/Variable.

I have already seen that you can pass a variable in the URL, but not how to write a variable dynamically after the URL from a e.g. Text Box.

[How to pass a URL input parameter value to Blazor page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299196/how-to-pass-a-url-input-parameter-value-to-blazor-page)

```html
<input @bind="ErrorCode"/>

<!--With the Input i fetch the a data from a database (searching for the right dataset with the input-ErrorCode).


The data i fetched from database is shown e.g. in a table-->
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
<!--My Problem now is, when the person who searched for an ErrorCode, 
wants to send the URL to another person, the other person only gets the page, without an input value.-->
```

Comment: Can you post some code of the context in how you would use this?

Comment: Of course.

I have an input from a Textbox, where i get the value.
<input @bind="ErrorCode"/>

With the value I then get data from a database.

Now I would like to have, if someone copies the link, that a third person then comes over the link again to the same ErrorCode or to the same data set.

https://localhost:44305/ErrorCode.

Comment: Not quite what I meant.  Can you provide a simple page within the question that demonstrates what you want to achieve?  It doesn't need to work.  Where does "ErrorCode" get used in `https://localhost:44305/Variable` and where does `https://localhost:44305/Variable` navigate to?  Telling us stops us making assumptions which are all too often wide of the mark!

Comment: Im not quite sure, if that is what you meant, but i hope so :)

Comment: Getting there.  Where exactly does "the person who searched for an ErrorCode, 
get the url to send to someone else".  Which bit of code is constructing the URL from the variable/property you are binding the input to?  Or are they simply putting the "https://siteurl/errorcode"?

Comment: Thats what im searching for. A person who searched for a code is writing it into the input element and the corresponding dataset is shown. But if he copies the link, and send it to someone else, there is only a blank page, because the input variable is empty. So i want to safe the variable to the url, so the right dataset is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it. Im not quiet sure, if it is the best solution, but it works. Please correct me, if im wrong. :)

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
        <form>
            <input @bind="ErrorCode"/>
        </form>
        @code
        {
            System.Uri uri;

            protected override void OnInitialized()
            {
                uri = navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navigationManager.Uri);
                if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("ErrorCode", out var errorCodeValue))
                {
                    ErrorCode = errorCodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
```